# Person field showing differently in email

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, site-column

I am working on a work site with SP 2007 on which I have a list item with a Person field available to associate an employee with that item. When looking up an employee to fill that field I get their name. When I reference that field in an email, I get the employee's reference number for the company. What causes this and can I get the actual name to show in the email?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you may just need to change the field that is shown in your Person field. You might be showing User Name instead of Name? Just go into your list settings and click on the column's name to check out what you have at the **Show field:** dropdown.

Otherwise, if you have [Useful Sharepoint Designer Custom Workflow Activities](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/) installed, in your Sharepoint Designer workflow you can use the "Lookup site user property" action:

Lookup **this user** property for **this user** , store in Variable

Put **ImnName** as the 1st **this user** (property), and choose your Person field in Current Item as the 2nd **this user** and assign it to a variable that you can then use as a Lookup under Worflow Data in your email.